# Is there any way to find a process (or at least the existence of a process) by working directory?

Tags: shell-script, process

I know that you can find the working directory of a process a few different ways, but is there any way to do the reverse? I have some server applications written in node that are unfortunately tricky to tell apart as processes (they all show up as `node server.js` in a `ps` output) and I would like to have a simple way to determine whether or not a specific server was running.

In other words the question I need answered is; given directory `/x/y/z`, is there a `node server.js` process running with the working directory `/x/y/z`?

Currently my best attempt is to do `ps -ef | grep "[n]ode server.js"`, cutting the PID and looping over them, checking `pwdx` for each PID. It works, but it's cumbersome and I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pwdx accepts PIDS then you can use:

```
$ pwdx $(ps -C "node server.js" --format pid --no-headers)
2781: /home/user
4405: /home/user/src.git/
```

And possibly define a function in your .zshrc or .bashrc:

```
function select_by_dir()
{
  if (( $# == 0))l then
    pwdx $(ps -C "node server.js" --format pid --no-headers) 
  else
    pwdx $(ps -C "node server.js" --format pid --no-headers) | grep $1
  fi
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure which part of your `ps` call it specifically objects to, but it fails with `error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)`. I perhaps should have specified that I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. Edit: Actually, it might just be that `node server.js` is missing quotes.

Comment: It hadn't really occurred to me that `pwdx` accepted any number of `PID`s. That's very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `ps` you can use `pgrep`. Possibly there will be no errors

Comment: `pgrep` doesn't work for this at all. The only way to get the `PID`s with that seems to be `pgrep node`, but that has too many false positives.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
pwdx `pgrep "server.js"`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just search `/proc`.

This will list all your pids for which you know the cwd and show the cwd next to it:

```
(cd /proc/; for p in [0-9]*; do
   cwd="$(readlink "$p/cwd")" || continue; echo "$p $cwd";
done)
```

You can `grep` that or insert your matcher right into the loop:

```
(cd /proc/; for p in [0-9]*; do
   cwd="$(readlink "$p/cwd")" || continue;
   [ "$cwd" != "$THE_CWD_IM_LOOKING_FOR" ] || { echo "$p"; break; }
done)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, if you "node" is the only process

```
pwdx `pidof node`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @skwllsp I've come up with the following bash function that solves the issue:

```
function is-server-running {
    local path=$(realpath "${1-.}")
    pwdx $(ps -C "node server.js" --format pid --no-headers) | grep --silent "$path"
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The commands [fuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)) and [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) both list processes that have a file open. In this context, having a file open includes a process's current directory.

With `fuser`, you only get process IDs, so you need to call `ps` to get the command name.

```
pids=$(fuser -s /x/y/z 2>/dev/null | tr ' ' ',')
pids=${pids#,}
node_pids=$(ps -p "$pids" -o pid=,args= | awk '$2 == "node" && $3 == "server.js" {print $1}')
kill $node_pids
```

With `lsof`, you can specify that you only want processes with that current directory (as opposed to e.g. currently listing the directory contents). You can get the command name with the `c` output specified, but not the arguments.

```
pids=$(lsof -F p -a -d cwd . | sed '1s/^p//; s/p/,/' | tr -d \\n)
```